# Crash with UIWebView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, uikeyboard

I have a Xamarin.iOS application that wraps UIWebView. Unfortunately, I'm receiving significant number of crashes in the Firebase console; it occurs only on iPhone with iOS 10, iPad doesn't have this issue.

Personally I can't reproduce the crash, so I have only stacktrace:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
1   libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 115024
2   UIKit               -[_UIKeyboardTextSelectionController selectTextWithGranularity:atPoint:executionContext:] + 5209476
3   UIKit               -[_UIKeyboardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureController oneFingerForcePan:] + 5624368
4   UIKit               -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 6166732
5   UIKit               _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 6181120
6   UIKit               _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 1700016
7   UIKit               -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 266176
8   UIKit               _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 6116260
9   UIKit               -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 6115188
10  UIKit               -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 6111776
11  UIKit               -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 258892
12  UIKit               -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 65404
13  UIKit               __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 8428060
14  UIKit               __handleEventQueue + 8405368
15  UIKit               __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 8406436
16  CoreFoundation      __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 898088
17  CoreFoundation      __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 896408
18  CoreFoundation      __CFRunLoopRun + 887204
19  CoreFoundation      CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 36256
20  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 49264
21  UIKit               UIApplicationMain + 478360
22  XamarinApp.iOS      (wrapper_managed-to-native)_UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (<unknown>:1)
23  XamarinApp.iOS      Main (UIApplication.cs:79)
24  XamarinApp.iOS      XamarinApp_iOS_XamarinApp_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 39656
25  XamarinApp.iOS      wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 634656
26  Mono                4316120312 + 378104
27  Mono                4316622816 + 880608
28  Mono                4316635652 + 893444
29  Mono                4316004656 + 262448
30  XamarinApp.iOS      xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:480)
31  XamarinApp.iOS      main (main.m:131)
32  libdyld.dylib       start + 17816
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Migrating to WKWebView is not an option for me since the app works quite a lot with cookies.

Comment: That native stack trace looks like it's pointing at a button event rather than something related to your UIWebview, I don't suppose you have any navigation buttons as part of your application?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Indeed, the app contains an additional screen (w/ navigation bar) than is being opened automatically on start in some situations. However, according to Firebase analytics, the crash can occur even if that screen was not opened. And navigation bar is hidden on the screen with UIWebView.

Comment: You must review Bugzilla of Xamarin because Xamarin have a lot of bugs, and update Core when fixed.

Comment: @JosePoseS there is nothing similar in Bugzilla. Because stacktrace contains some private UIKit classes, I guess there is a bug in UIWebView (fairly bugly component, actually), so I wonder if there is some workaround.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin can you debug this crash with xamarin studio and see trace? Because all crashes of iOS kenerl with Xamarin put the same. If you debug this xamarin shows better log and you can search in Bugzilla.

Comment: @JosePoseS Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it.